# Benefits of Sass over Stylus

Tags: css, sass, stylus

I've inherited a project that uses Stylus as its CSS preprocessor.

Originally, I wanted to migrate this to Sass, as I was always led to believe this was the 'best' preprocessor, but having read some articles, the differences appear to be very minor, and there doesn't appear to be anything that can't be done in one that you can't do in the other. Articles shy from definitively stating one is best and instead just give an overview of the various options.

Is there any significant benefits of one over the other, or are the differences too minor to merit changing?

Comment: The question was: is there a big difference between SASS and Stylus? The OP didn’t find any. – How will this be “almost entirely based on opinions”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the biggest differences are not in the way that you write your css, but in the way the preprocessor handles your requests.

I really don't think that is by chance that SASS is so much more popular than all the others (even LESS, wich is my choice), and one more thing that really matters, is the size of the users community, that saves a lot of time when searching for bug solutions, tutorials, etc..

So, in a nutshell, I think that SASS is technically superior from Stylus and LESS, is evolving, and has a great community.

But, of course, it's all a matter of choice/opnion.

Comment: +1 for size of the users community as a primary consideration.

Comment: Obviously this is a subjective question (may explain the votes to close..) but I'm marking this as accepted as it seems to take all the various considerations into account. Thanks!